# pandas/scikit learn combining columns

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a pandas dataframe with the following columns:

```
id, cookie_id, file_loc
```

I am doing a stratified split using scikit-learn like so (stratified by `id`):

```
sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
X=df['file_loc']
y=df['id']
for train_index, test_index in sss.split(X, y):
    # print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

However, I would like `X` to be considered as `[df['cookie_id']`, `df['file_loc']]`, so that `X_train`, `y_train` contain both the info (`cookie_id` and `file_loc`), but for some reason I am not able to figure out how to do this :(

Any pointers would be great.

Comment: sk-learn use numpy in the background, not pandas DataFrame. Look closer some of the examples, it may not produce a 2D array but something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you may be looking for:

```
X=df[['cookie_id','file_loc']]
```

Comment: this does not work. it throws: `KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([ 764,  999,  919,  424, 1637, 1438,  524,  317, 1295,  208,\n            ...\n             951,  744, 1679,  774, 1627, 1508,  669,  367, 1475,  737],\n           dtype='int64', length=1378)] are in the [columns]"`

Comment: Could you edit you question and include part of the dataframe?